# API function not working with PostgreSQL table when removing row

Tags: javascript, postgresql, delete-row

I am trying to figure out how an API works where we don't have the support anymore from the creator.

**Basic set-up;**
We have a PostgreSQL table running which contains events data (date, subject, time, etc)

There is an API which lets us book new events. This works fine.
I see there is also an option to DELETE an event, but this is not working as it should. Therefore I am trying to figure out where it's going wrong.

Here is an example of the POST new meeting in the API .js file (which works)

```
router.post('/meeting/post', (req, res) => {
    Meeting.query().insertGraph(req.body)
        .then(() => {
            res.json("post ok");
        });
});
```

So far, so good.

But the delete function is a puzzle for me(can't get it to work);

```
router.get('/meeting/delete', (req, res) => {
    const date = moment().utc().subtract(3, "days").format();

    Meeting.query().withGraphFetched(neededTables)
        .where('id', '!=', 1)
        .andWhere('end_time', '<', date)
        .then(meetings => {
            meetings.forEach(meeting => {
                const folderPath = `${appConfig.backgroundsFilepath}resources/images/meeting-${meeting.id}`;
                if (fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
                    meeting.backgrounds.forEach(background => {
                        const sides = ['left', 'middle', 'right'];
                        sides.forEach((side) => {
                            const filePath = background[side].replace('./', appConfig.backgroundsFilepath);
                            if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
                                fs.rmSync(filePath);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    fs.rmdirSync(folderPath);
                }
            });
        });

    Meeting.query().delete()
        .where('id', '!=', 1)
        .andWhere('end_time', '<', date)
        .then(() => {
            res.json("delete ok");
        });
});
```

In postman, I post a GET to [localhost]/meeting/delete
with a body containing;

```
        "id": 5
    }
```

Then I get a perfect return:

```
"delete ok"
```

Only when I look at the table data, the row with ID:5 is still there...

I am a bit of a noob with JS / PostgreSQL / API's so I am quite lost here. I hope someone has a good idea on what to check.

Comment: What ORM are you using? What is this `Meeting.query().delete()` stuff?

Comment: You haven't shown the code that processes the request body of that `/meeting/delete` request, only the `/meeting/post` route. But if your goal is to delete the meeting with id 5, then `.where('id', '!=', 1).andWhere('end_time', '<', date)` appears to be the wrong query for that job

Comment: That delete function, at a naive reading, seems like it is intended to delete _everything_ that is NOT ID 1, AND ends before 3 days from now.  Maybe you're looking at the wrong `delete` implementation?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a REST(ful) API? These `/post` and `/delete` endpoints look really wrong.